# Submitting ACM Conference papers to ArXiv

Tags: arxiv, open-access, acm

I'm a little confused. The [ACM Author Rights and Publishing Policy](http://www.acm.org/publications/policies/copyright_policy) states:

> ACM authors hold the right to post copies of their own peer-reviewed accepted ACM works on any non-commercial repository or aggregation that does not duplicate ACM tables of contents, i.e., whose patterns of links do not substantially duplicate an ACM-copyrighted volume or issue. Non-commercial repositories are here understood as repositories owned by non-profit organizations that do not charge a fee for accessing deposited articles and that do not sell advertising or otherwise profit from serving articles.

However, the [ACM Fair Access](http://www.acm.org/publications/fair-access/acm-fair-access?pageIndex=4) site states:

> **Can I publish the published version of my publication on arXiv?**
>       No. An ACM author cannot grant arXiv.org or any other publisher rights to distribute their works that have been published by ACM.

SHERPA/Romeo shows ACM as being a "Green Publisher", which would support the case that I can upload to ArXiv.

[Dissem.in](http://dissem.in/publisher/19/) states that I can upload pre- or postprints under certain circumstances, but does not explicitly mention Arxiv, positively or negatively.

So, what is it? Can I submit a paper I published with an ACM Conference (ACM WiSec, if that makes a difference) to ArXiv or not? As I understand it, ArXiv is a non-profit, so it would fit the terms of the publishing policy. Or is this related to the rights you have to grant ArXiv upon submission?

If I can only publish a specific version of the paper, which one?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

This is a matter of obsolete documentation.

The [current version](http://www.acm.org/publications/policies/copyright_policy) of the "ACM Author Rights and Publishing Policy" you linked to is v9, last revised in 1/2016. This version says that authors have the right to:

> Post the Accepted Version of the Work on (1) the Author's home page, (2) the Owner's institutional repository, (3) any repository legally mandated by an agency funding the research on which the Work is based, and **(4) any non-commercial repository or aggregation that does not duplicate ACM tables of contents**, i.e., whose patterns of links do not substantially duplicate an ACM-copyrighted volume or issue. Non-commercial repositories are here understood as repositories owned by non-profit organizations that do not charge a fee for accessing deposited articles and that do not sell advertising or otherwise profit from serving articles.

(emphasis mine.)

The [previous version](http://web.archive.org/web/20151213144527/http://www.acm.org/publications/policies/copyright_policy), v9 with a 5/2015 last revision date, only gave authors the right to

> Post the Accepted Version of the Work on (1) the Author's home page, (2) the Owner's institutional repository, or (3) any repository legally mandated by an agency funding the research on which the Work is based.

The [Fair Access FAQ page](http://web.archive.org/web/20150920175717/https://www.acm.org/publications/fair-access/acm-fair-access?pageIndex=4) is from before January 2016, and reflects the old policy.

The current policy as of January 2016 does allow the accepted version of the work to be posted on "any non-commercial repository or aggregation that does not duplicate ACM tables of contents" such as arXiv.

malexmave [confirms after contacting ACM](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/65531/submitting-acm-conference-papers-to-arxiv/65535?noredirect=1#comment158746_65535):

> FAQ was indeed outdated. Posting the peer-reviewed / accepted version to ArXiv and other non-commercial repositories is fine (but not the final version). Policy change does not apply retroactively, only to new papers under the new policy.

Comment: Interesting. Do you by any chance know if this applies retroactively to conferences from before that change?

Comment: Now I am confused, only *two days ago* we signed an ACM copyright transfer agreement with the following terms: "(iii) Post the Accepted Version of the Work on (1) the Authors home page, (2) the Owner's institutional repository, or (3) any repository legally mandated by an agency funding the research on which the Work is based." There was no point (4) there? Have you seen the new terms in use in some ACM conferences already?

Comment: (In any case I deleted my answer as it was based on the old terms.)

Comment: @JukkaSuomela I'm not at all surprised that the copyright transfer form hasn't been updated.  However, it does say on it, "*ACM authors retain all proprietary rights other than copyright **including** a set of “Retained Rights” stated on the Form.  (Also see the ACM Copyright Policy, §2.4, §2.5 and the Permissions Policy, §3 for further details).*" (emphasis mine) The list of retained rights on the form need not be comprehensive.

Comment: @malexmave I don't know the answer to that.

Comment: @ff524 Okay, I guess I'll have to contact the ACM, then. I'll leave this question open until then and will update you and accept your answer once the ACM gives a definitive statement. Thanks!

Comment: @ff524 results are in. FAQ was indeed outdated. Posting the peer-reviewed / accepted version to ArXiv and other non-commercial repositories is fine (but not the final version). Policy change does not apply retroactively, only to new papers under the new policy. Feel free to add this to your answer so it isn't buried in the comments, I'll accept it now either way.

Comment: How does this go hand-in-hand with Supplementary Material? I am assuming the final version doesn't have the Supplementary Material with it. So the final version  + revisions + Supp Material is allowed on ArXiv?

Comment: @malexmave Sorry if this is obvious, but what exactly is the "peer-reviewed" / "accepted" version? In particular, am I allowed to put a post-print on arxiv, i.e., including the final edits after receiving peer review feedback but without ACM branding etc.?

Answer (score 1):

The ACM offers guidelines for [Prior Publication and Simultaneous Submissions](https://www.acm.org/publications/policies/simultaneous-submissions).  Information there (from April 2018) extends [this answer](https://academia.stackexchange.com/a/65535/94523) if the paper is a technical report *prior to submission* or *under review* as opposed to being *already accepted*. The guidelines state

> Issuing the paper as a technical report, posting the paper on a web site, or presenting the paper at a workshop or conference that does not publish formally reviewed proceedings does not disqualify it from appearing in an ACM publication.

I assume for the case that the manuscript is not yet submitted or still under review, arXiv would count as "issuing the paper as a technical report, posting the paper on a web site."

I understand the following: Overall, ACM usually allows researchers to archive their manuscripts prior to submission, during review, and after peer-review/acceptance as long as the manuscript is not equal to the official ACM publication and, after publication, contains a corresponding link to this official (i.e. formally reviewed) publication.

Please, let me know if this is incorrect. [Some philosophical background](https://robjhyndman.com/hyndsight/working-papers/) on why publishers should be less restrictive anyway.