# Why would a conference discourage authors to submit their papers to pre-submissions platforms (e.g., arXiv) before submitting them to the conference?

Tags: publications, peer-review, arxiv

I asked some conference organizers whether authors may submit papers to arXiv before submitting to the conference, and got the following reply:

> though not encouraging it, [conference name] allows archiving pre-submissions on platforms such as arXiv: therefore you can upload there your article before submitting it to the conference.

Why would a conference discourage authors to submit their papers to pre-submissions platforms (e.g., arXiv) before submitting them to the conference?

---

The proceedings of the conference are licensed under a Creative Commons Attribution-NonCommercial 4.0 International License, so 
the license isn't an issue. The only issue I can see is that it may jeopardize the anonymity of the authors (the conference review process is double blinded). Is there any other downside?

I asked the conference organizers why they do not encourage archiving pre-submissions on platforms such as arXiv, but I haven't heard back from them.

**This question is different from the question [Submitting ACM Conference papers to ArXiv](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/65531/452): the latter focuses on licenses, whereas here the license isn't an issue.**

Comment: The reply suggests that the conference doesn't endorse such behaviour, which isn't the same as discouraging such behaviour. The conference might not endorse such behaviour because the publisher might discourage such behaviour, and the conference organizers don't want to cause friction.

Comment: A reason could be: The conference wants to have original papers, not papers already known to the community.

Comment: "not encouraging" != "discouraging". To me this simply sounds like ass-covering language: The author of the mail was worried that someone somewhere might otherwise view his sentence as an official encouragement which he was not entitled to give.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Submitting ACM Conference papers to ArXiv](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/65531/submitting-acm-conference-papers-to-arxiv)

Comment: @dsfgsho The question you linked to is about license issues

Comment: Could one of the 4 close voters explain their votes?

Answer (score 3):

Here is a nice article that explains your question from [ACL2017](https://chairs-blog.acl2017.org/2017/03/02/arxiv-and-double-blind-reviewing-revisited/) . Main aim is to protect double blind review system.